# Trackpad does not work in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Inspiron 1525. Now the trackpad no longer works and I have to use a USB mouse. Would changing the Desktop environment from Unity back to GNOME help or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My first guess was correct and it was Unity. Installed GNOME3 and everything works fine. Looks great too.